# asynchronous post request in python

Tags: python, post, asynchronous, python-requests

I have a python script which has a line that makes a post request as shown below:

```
rsp = requests.post(img_url, data=img_json_data, headers=img_headers)
print rsp # just for debugging
```

But suppose I don't want my script to keep waiting for the response, but instead run the above lines asynchronously in parallel to the rest of the code. What would be the easiest way to do so?

Comment: Create a Thread with a Queue. Put your post calls in the queue, make the thread do them. Retrieve results in another Queue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a class that allow easy parallel execution on multiple workers.

Basically it creates worker threads, that wait for job in a Queue.
Once you put a task they execute it and put the results in another Queue.
`join()` will wait until everything is done, then we empty the results queue and return as an array.

```
from Queue import Queue
import logging
from threading import Thread


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Parallel(object):
    def __init__(self, thread_num=10):
        # create queues
        self.tasks_queue = Queue()
        self.results_queue = Queue()

        # create a threading pool
        self.pool = []
        for i in range(thread_num):
            worker = Worker(i, self.tasks_queue, self.results_queue)
            self.pool.append(worker)
            worker.start()

        logger.debug('Created %s workers',thread_num)

    def add_task(self, task_id, func, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Add task to queue, they will be started as soon as added
        :param func: function to execute
        :param args: args to transmit
        :param kwargs: kwargs to transmit
        """

        logger.debug('Adding one task to queue (%s)', func.__name__)
        # add task to queue
        self.tasks_queue.put_nowait((task_id, func, args, kwargs))
        pass

    def get_results(self):
        logger.debug('Waiting for processes to ends')
        self.tasks_queue.join()
        logger.debug('Processes terminated, fetching results')

        results = []
        while not self.results_queue.empty():
            results.append(self.results_queue.get())

        logger.debug('Results fetched, returning data')
        return dict(results)

class Worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, thread_id, tasks, results):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

        self.id = thread_id
        self.tasks = tasks
        self.results = results
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        logger.debug('Worker %s launched', self.id)
        while True:
            task_id, func, args, kwargs = self.tasks.get()
            logger.debug('Worker %s start to work on %s', self.id, func.__name__)
            try:
                self.results.put_nowait((task_id, func(*args, **kwargs)))
            except Exception as err:
                logger.debug('Thread(%s): error with task %s\n%s', self.id, repr(func.__name__), err)
            finally:
                logger.debug('Worker %s finished work on %s', self.id, func.__name__)
                self.tasks.task_done()


import requests
# create parallel instance with 4 workers
parallel = Parallel(4)

# launch jobs
for i in range(20):
    parallel.add_task(i, requests.post, img_url, data=img_json_data, headers=img_headers)

# wait for all jobs to return data
print parrallel.get_results()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use celery for the same. With celery the processing will be async and you can check for status as well as result. For further info click [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to queue this task for asynchronous processing.

There are multiple options here :

1. celery which has larger learning curve for a newbie. [check here](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
2. python-rq which is relatively very light weight and a goto library. [check here](http://python-rq.org/)

You can use any of the message queues among redis,rabbitmq etc